# My rankx function return 1 as a result for all the projects

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]I have a table t1, containing project, bugcount along with other column.

I am suming up my bugcount for each project at report level.

Now I want to rank my project based on the highest to lowest bugcounts.

I tried different dax I could search online to get my result but all of them are fetching me value 1 for all the project.

Please find the screenshot of the attached code that I have put as different variables... I tried all of them... None worked.

Also with the solution, if someone could please help me where am I going wrong, would help me with a clear concept.

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure using the following dax formula:

```
Ranking = RANKX( ALLSELECTED( Table[Projectname] ), CALCULATE( SUM(Table[BugsCount]) ),, 1 )
```

This measure returns the same value for tie bugcounts. Hope it helps.

Comment: No it doesn't, if u see my screenshot... U can see a var rankviaproject has the code that u mentioned..  I have tried that too.. returns one for all column